# Set Text in Editor Component in Combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

My goal is to create a filtered combobox.

I create an editable combobox. When the user enters text, the code searches matching items in the model. When the user leaves the combobox, the code selects the selected item from the list. Further, the text from the editor component gets the value of the selected item.

When the focus goes back to the combobox via shift + tab, the editor component gets the text of the selected element. After releasing the shift key, the keylistener runs.  In this case, the editor component contains the text entered previously, e.g., the value set when the focus is lost.

How can I set the text of the editorComponent to make it persist?

Here's the code:

```
package de.ccw.reports.gui.incomingOrder.MyComboBox;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

import de.ccw.commons.ui.comp.XComboBox;

public class FilterableComboBox<E> extends XComboBox<E> {

    ComboBoxModel<E> originalModel;
    DefaultComboBoxModel<E> filteredModel;

    JTextComponent editorComp;
    JList<E> list;

    public FilterableComboBox(ComboBoxModel<E> aModel) {
        super();
        receivePopupList();
        originalModel = aModel;

        filteredModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        setModel(filteredModel);

        editorComp = (JTextComponent) getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        editorComp.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                System.out.println("focusLostStart=" + getSelectedItem() + "|" + editorComp.getText());

                String text = editorComp.getText();
                editorComp.setText("");
                setSelectedItem(null);

                if(list.getSelectedIndex() != -1 && text.isEmpty() == false){
                    setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex());
                    editorComp.setText(getSelectedItem().toString());
                }

                System.out.println("focusLostEnd=" + getSelectedItem() + "|" + editorComp.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                System.out.println("focusGainedStart=" + getSelectedItem() + "|" + editorComp.getText());
                E element = getSelectedItem();
                String text = editorComp.getText();
                performModelFilter(null);
                showPopup();
                setSelectedItem(element);
                editorComp.setText(text);
                editorComp.selectAll();
                System.out.println("focusGainedEnd=" + getSelectedItem() + "|" + editorComp.getText());
            }

        });
        editorComp.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            String filterBkp = "";
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                String filter = editorComp.getText();

                System.out.println("keyReleased-" + filterBkp + filter);

                if(filter.equals(filterBkp) == false)
                    refreshModel();

                filterBkp = filter;
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });

        setEditable(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void receivePopupList() {
        BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup) getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
        list = popup.getList();
    }


    private void refreshModel() {

        String filter = editorComp.getText();

        performModelFilter(filter);

        editorComp.setText(filter);

    }

    private void performModelFilter(String filter) {
        System.out.println("performModelFilter-" + filter);

        filteredModel.removeAllElements();

        for(int i = 0; i < originalModel.getSize(); i++){
            E element = originalModel.getElementAt(i);
            String value = element.toString().toUpperCase();
            if (filter == null || value.contains(filter.toUpperCase())) {
                filteredModel.addElement(element);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        FilterableComboBox<String> combo = new FilterableComboBox<>(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[]{"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mnoabc", "pqrdef"}));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JTextField(20));
        frame.add(combo);
        frame.add(new JTextField(20));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: AAAAHHHHHHRRRRRGGGGG. I´m so stupid. I get the problem. The KeyListener saves the searchtext. when the focus gets on the combobox again i have to set the selected item text in to the save string.

Comment: (from Abstract/PlainDocument) is selected the last indicies, there is selection if you want or not on one of Item, use standard autocomplete JComboBox/JTextField (there you cann't see/found out something about KeyEvents from KeyListener), leave fitering, to sort array before usage - better performance